# Receive Error 500 Internal Server Error Phpmyadmin

Tags: laravel, ubuntu

I get:

> 500 Internal server Error

while importing and exporting database from phpMyAdmin installed on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: show what error you get

Comment: importing via laravel ? share code ?

Answer (score 1):

There are too many possibilities.

To figure out the detail:

you can check php error log to found out the problem.

For general setup of apache, error log is at the following place.

```
/var/log/apache2/error.log
```

Please share the latest error on the error log.